# How can I stop video from playing in background when only another app is open?

Tags: flutter

How can I stop video from playing in background when only another app is open?

otherwise continuously playing video

I am using chewie: ^0.9.10 for flutter

Please help me

Comment: You should dispose Chewie controller in the onDispose of your player widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should dispose the controllers as stated here: [chewie_dispose](https://pub.dev/packages/chewie#use-it:~:text=Please%20make%20sure%20to%20dispose%20both,dispose%20method%20of%20the%20a%20StatefulWidget%3A)

```
@override
void dispose() {
  videoPlayerController.dispose();
  chewieController.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Requirement- Background video is stop when in case of open another application..
otherwise the video playing continuously

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with that to be honest.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Or did you find the solution by yourself?

Comment: I Have don't stop the backround video untill user open another application video
like as Amazon prime app

Comment: This issue is already reported on Github. Follow ariefwijaya's advice: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34646#issuecomment-643756406-permalink:~:text=You%20can%20use%20this%20useful%20plugin

Comment: I am not satisfy with this suggestions

Comment: Why? [onAudioFocusLost](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service#example:~:text=onAudioFocusLost(AudioInterruption%20interruption)%20%7B%7D) should do what you want. Just pause the video when the method is called.